# How to resolve this error in python ____?

Tags: error-handling

I am new in staksoverflow and i writed a code in python.

```py
x=int(input('enter a number'))
raise ValueError('expected 1 value') if x !=1 else print('correct')
```

it shows an error on initialising
x with value 1.

**TypeError: exceptions must be derived from BaseException.**

Answer (score 0):

```py
raise ValueError('expected 1 value') if x != 1 else print('correct')
```

You cannot do this. It looks like you think it works this way:

```py
<raise ValueError('expected 1 value')> if x != 1 else <print('correct')>
```

whereas it *actually* works this way:

```py
raise <<ValueError('expected 1 value')> if x != 1 else <print('correct')>>
```

In other words, the entire expression `ValueError('expected 1 value') if x != 1 else print('correct')` is the parameter to the `raise` statement so, in the case of `x == 1`,  it's trying to use the result of the `print` statement as an exception to raise. Hence the error, since `print` returns `None` rather than an exception you can raise.

A better way would probably be:

```py
if x != 1:
    raise ValueError('expected 1 value')
else:
    print('correct')
```

Comment: Ohh... I got my mistake.